# How to Update mysql timestamp column using java prepare statement?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have created table as below:

```sql
create table sample(id int not null,created_at timestamp,updated_at timestamp,name varchar(100),primary key(id));
```

have tried to update the column in different ways as below, but am not able to update the time:

```java
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
java.util.Date now = calender.getTime();
java.sql.Timestamp updatedAt = new java.sql.Timestamp(now.getTime());
stmt.setTimestamp(2, updatedAt);

java.sql.Timestamp  updatedAt = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
stmt.setTimestamp(2, updatedAt);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String updatedAt =sdf.format(date);
stmt.setString(2, updatedAt);

final java.util.Date updatedAt = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
stmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(updatedAt.getTime()));
```

please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please tell us, what is happening?

Comment: unable to update the time in database table , it is updating like 2014-07-29 00:00:00

Comment: your database has a wrong type?

Comment: No i have not written any trigger @Scary Wombat

Comment: You should separate the code or use one that didn't work, or post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2):

The `java.sql.Date()` strips time portion of your date due to SQL convention. You can check [SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).

```
Timestamp updatedAt = new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
stmt.setTimestamp(2, updatedAt);
```

Comment: according to his code `java.sql.Timestamp updatedAt = new java.sql.Timestamp(now.getTime());
stmt.setTimestamp(2, updatedAt);` he already does

Comment: also according to javadoc sql.Date is `A thin wrapper around a millisecond value that allows JDBC to identify this as an SQL DATE value`

Comment: @ScaryWombat His code is wrong, and it didn't used milliseconds to create a timestamp.

Comment: Yes @Scary Wombat have already tried the above code but as date is having milliseconds we are unable to update the column

Comment: @RomanC `java.util.Date now`  `Date.getime ()` returns millseconds

Comment: @ScaryWombat I used this code without any problem, and never `java.sql.Date` but `java.util.Date` if needed.

Comment: @RomanC I agree your code should work, but it also the same as the OP's first try.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Because may be OP updated it several times at least one which was last is wrong.

Comment: @ScaryWombat In the code above when running it will fail on the last try following a commit statement, that is missed there and then everything is rolled back.

Comment: @RomanC I thought that the OP was simply listing 4 different ways that he had tried to update the field.  I am getting more and more confused everytime I read it.